# MVC Regular Expression Data Attribute Validation is firing incorrectly

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc

The following Regular Expression attribute is firing an error no matter what is entered into the field. This is happening on the client side. Furthermore, it is displaying the generic message instead of the specified one. Can you help?

public class RegisterModel

```
{

    [Required]

    [StringLength(63, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]

    [RegularExpression(@"/^[a-z\d]+([-_][a-z\d]+)*$/i",ErrorMessage="The Site Name can only contain letters from a-z (no accents), numbers from 0-9 and non consecutive hyphens or underscores.")]

    [Display(Name = "Site Name")]

    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

The following different Regex works so it must be a problem with the expression itself or the @ (string literal) character which is needed as the \d combination is a C# escape character.

RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "The Site Name can only contain letters from a-z (no accents), numbers from 0-9 and non consecutive hyphens or underscores.")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work fine.

[RegularExpression(@"^(a-z0-9{0,61}[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "The Site Name can only contain letters from a-z (no accents), numbers from 0-9 and non consecutive hyphens or underscores.")]